# Missing statement in a proof Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I am reading the proof for the existence of the Jordan normal form.

I know the Fitting lemma.

I am missing one thing though, I mean the proof in my book seems to have this particular thing missing.

I think I am missing this statement.

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional nonzero vector space over the field $F$ which is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$, and $T$ has a single characteristic root $s$ in $\mathbb{C}$ which is also in $F$. Then there exists a positive integer $m$ such that

$V = Ker(T-s.e)^m$,

where $e$ is the identity map of $V$.

Is this statement true? I think it is because the text I am reading seems to assume it is true. How do we prove it?

Comment: What is the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Must be $(s-x)$ to some power $k$ but I am not sure exactly. I read too much theory in the last few days. I haven't quite digested it yet. Can I claim the power $k$ is the dimension $n$ of $V$? And then, if so, what follows further?

Comment: Since $s$ is the only characteristic value of $T$ over $\mathbb C$, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $p(x)=(x-s)^n$, where $n=\dim V$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p(T)=0$. Therefore $(T-s\operatorname{Id})^n=0$, although there may exist a smaller positive integer $m$ such that $(T-s\operatorname{Id})^m=0$.

Comment: @user1551 Cayley-Hamilton theorem is proved later in the textbook I am reading. I cannot use it here. So I need some proof using simpler arguments. Also, isn't the polynomial $(s-x)^n$? I know the leading coefficient has to be $(-1)^n$

Comment: You may also triangularise $T$ and the problem boils down to showing that a sufficiently high powers of a strictly triangular matrix is zero.

Comment: @peter.petrov Both $\det(T-x\operatorname{Id})$ and $\det(x\operatorname{Id}-T)$ are accepted conventions for characteristic polynomial. Older books (esp. the Russian ones, in my impression) used to adopt the former, but the latter seems to be more popular in more recent books.

Answer (score 1):

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, so is $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$. Therefore $\{\operatorname{Id},T,T^2,\ldots\}$ is a linearly dependent family of linear operators, meaning that some non-trivial linear combination $\sum_{k=0}^mc_kT^k$ is zero, i.e., some nonzero polynomial in $T$ evaluates to zero. Among all such polynomials, pick one with the lowest degree and call it $f(x)$. By dividing each coefficient of $f$ by the leading one, we may assume that $f(x)$ is monic. This is known as the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Factorise $f$ as $\prod_{i=1}^m(x-\lambda_i)$, where $m=\deg f$. If $T-\lambda_k\operatorname{Id}$ is nonsingular for some $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, then for $g(x)=\prod_{i\neq k}(x-\lambda_i)$, we have $g(T)=(T-\lambda_k\operatorname{Id})^{-1}f(T)=0$, which is a contradiction to the minimality of $\deg f$. Therefore $T-\lambda_i\operatorname{Id}$ must be singular for each $i$. However, by assumption, the only characteristic value of $T$ is $s$. Therefore $\lambda_i=s$ for all $i$. Consequently, $f(x)=(x-s)^m$ and $(T-s\operatorname{Id})^m=f(T)=0$.